# Resharper dupfinder finds reverse assignments

Tags: resharper, code-duplication

In our dupfinder output we have many "duplicate" code fragments of the following form:

**Duplicated Fragments:**

**Fragment 1 in file (...) from line 331 to line 335**

```
entity.some_prop_1 = model.SomeProp1;
entity.some_prop_2 = model.SomeProp2;
entity.some_prop_3 = model.SomeProp3;
entity.some_prop_4 = model.SomeProp4;
entity.some_prop_5 = model.SomeProp5;
```

**Fragment 2 in file (...) from line 470 to line 474**

```
model.SomeProp1 = entity.some_prop_1;
model.SomeProp2 = entity.some_prop_2;
model.SomeProp3 = entity.some_prop_3;
model.SomeProp4 = entity.some_prop_4;
model.SomeProp5 = entity.some_prop_5;
```

How is it that dupfinder regards fragments like these as duplicates? They do the exact opposite. One maps from model to entity, the other maps the way back. Is there a way how these could be merged into one code fragment only? Or can the false positive be prevented with any setting?

My search on google was not successful so far.

Comment: It took me a second to realize you were talking about the duplicate finder in the [ReSharper command line tools](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/09/03/duplicate-finder-part-of-resharper-command-line-tools/), not the actual VS extension. This is a non-answer, but if those results are wrong, I also suggest you report it as a bug on [ReSharper's bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP). Make sure you select `ReSharper Automation Tools (command line)` under Subsystem.

Comment: @Igal thank you for the feedback. OK, I wouldn't have dared to think of it as a bug. It looks so advanced that I thought it was by design (a simple text comparison would not have revealed this as a duplicate). But I'll report it and see what they answer.

Comment: @chiccodoro Good luck! Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with the command-line tools to know how to interpret those results, I'm sure JetBrains guys will help!

Comment: @siride, Igal - done: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-413790